# Convert current GMT time into CST timezone using java

Tags: java, date, calendar, simpledateformat

I am trying to convert current GMT time to CST time using JDK8. But my code always returns the same time for both the timezones. I also verified getAvailableIDs() has "CST".

```
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
            cal.setTimeZone(timeZone);

            // System.out.println("GMT time = " + cal.getTime());

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            sdf.setTimeZone(timeZone);
            String gmtDateStr = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
            System.out.println("Formatted GMT time = " + gmtDateStr);

            // To CST
            SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            TimeZone cst = TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST");
            sdf2.setTimeZone(cst);
            Date cstDate = sdf2.parse(gmtDateStr);

            // System.out.println("PARSED CST DATE = " + cstDate);

            Calendar cal2 = new GregorianCalendar();
            cal2.setTime(cstDate);
            cal2.setTimeZone(cst);
            String cstDateStr = sdf2.format(cal2.getTime());

            // System.out.println("cal2 time = " + cal2.getTime());
            System.out.println("FORMATTED CST DATE = " + cstDateStr);
```

What is wrong here? Can any one provide me an answer?

Comment: there is no CST zone ? what do you mean by CST ?

Comment: "CST" means Central Standard Time. I found this string in TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()

Comment: `CST` is not a real time zone. These 3-4 latter codes are not true time zones, are not standardized, and are not even unique! For example CST is commonly used for both Central Standard Time and China Standard Time. Use [proper time zone names](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in format `continent/region` such as `America/Chicago` or `America/Montreal` or `Africa/Tunis`.

Comment: You are using confusing troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to do all of this conversion to get time in your preferred timezone. You can simply do following..

```
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
        cal.setTimeZone(timeZone);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        sdf.setTimeZone(timeZone);
        String gmtDateStr = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
        System.out.println("Formatted GMT time = " + gmtDateStr);

        // To CST
        SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        TimeZone cst = TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST");
        sdf2.setTimeZone(cst);

        System.out.println("FORMATTED CST DATE = " + sdf2.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 3):

Java 8 `java.time` doesn't find a zone identified by `CST`

```
ZoneId cst = ZoneId.of("CST");
```

results in `java.time.zone.ZoneRulesException: Unknown time-zone ID: CST`. This makes sense as there is Central Standard Time in North America, China Standard Time, and possibly other.

If you mean Central Standard Time in North America which is represented by `America/Chicago`:

```
ZoneId gmt = ZoneId.of("GMT");
ZoneId cst = ZoneId.of("America/Chicago");
ZonedDateTime gmtTime = ZonedDateTime.now(gmt);
ZonedDateTime cstTime = gmtTime.withZoneSameInstant(cst);
```

Comment: i just came to write something like this answer lol, however he doesn't use java 8 time API

Comment: Good Answer, but I suggest excusing “CST” letters entirely as that is not a true time zone. Any such usage only confuses the issue. Programmers should train themselves to use only [true standardized time zone names](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) rather than those pseudo-zones.

Comment: In Java 8 you may find CST as alias for America/Chicago in [`ZoneId.SHORT_IDS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#SHORT_IDS), **but** as others have said, it is recommended not to. Instead use America/Chicago directly (unless “CST” is found in some legacy data that you cannot reasonably update).

Answer (score 2):

What is wrong with your code is all those calls to `Calendar.getTime()`. This returns a `Date` instance, and those objects do not have the concept of a time zone. So it is useless to set the time zone in the `Calendar` instances because you then discard that info when converting to `Date`.

Just specify the time zone in your formatter, as in Yogesh Badke's answer.

Comment: Being more precise: it is useless to set the `Calendar` time zone *in your example*. If you were making date/time calculations with those `Calendar` instances, it might or might not have an effect.