# How to get LocalTime at different time-zone?

Tags: java, date

I understand that LocalTime is time zone agnostic. But I would like to get hours in Central Standard Time (CST) zone. All I am given is time in String:

```
String start = "11:00" //11 am CST. 
LocalTime startTime = LocalTime.parse(start);
```

This is good but server is running in different time-zone. So it will interpret it as 11 am UTC. I want LocalTime to be in CST. I need to in CST.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208459/discussion-on-question-by-faraz-how-to-get-localtime-at-different-time-zone).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LocalDateTime.now()` is actually a shortcut for `LocalDateTime.now(Clock.systemDefaultZone())`, where `Clock.class` represents some date-time instant ([see docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html)), and static method `systemDefaultZone()` returns the date-time instant of your PC.

In your case it's possible to use "clock" for a different zone (zone with id="CST" doesn't exist but you can choose "America/Chicago" instead - see explanation [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49533117/5572007)).

```
LocalTime currentTime = LocalTime.now(Clock.system(ZoneId.of("America/Chicago")));
```

**UPD** Didn't understand the task properly. In this case it's actually easier to convert  `currentTime` instead of `startTime` to needed zone.

```
LocalTime currentTime = LocalTime.now(Clock.system(ZoneId.of("Europe/London")));
```

or, as Ole V.V. reminded:

```
LocalTime currentTime = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
```

then you can compare it with unmodified `startTime` (in this case - 11:00)

Comment: While this works, it really sounds like `LocalTime` is the wrong tool here. Why not `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetTime`. Or going from CST to UTC, passing UTC around, and finally going back to a zoned time.

Comment: @Zabuza I tend to agree with you. Myself, I prefer to work with "Clock" only while mocking the date-time in unit-tests.

Comment: @amseager it doesn't really answer my question. This is showing `now()` at CST. I want to convert my 11 to CST.

Comment: It doesn't really answers my question. But this gives me an idea.

Comment: It’s overly complicated. You need no `Clock`. Just `LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Chicago"))`.

Comment: @OleV.V. both ways are the same. `now(ZoneId zone)` is another shortcut method which calls `now(Clock.system(zone))` under the hood.

Comment: @Faraz I meant what you can set `currentTime` to different zone and then compare it with your `startTime`. You can, for example, set zone ("Europe/London") for `currentTime` - in this case it doesn't needed to convert `startTime` at all while comparing them.

Comment: @amseager I don’t care what it does under the hood (that’s why it’s kept under the hood). I care about keeping my own code simple, readable and maintainable. Therefore the suggestion.

Comment: @OleV.V. Technically, both methods are `public` and part of the API. About readability and stuff - it's just a matter of taste.

Comment: @amseager thanks. `then you can compare it with unmodified startTime (in this case - 11:00)` -> this part answers my question. Thanks